# (за двадцать лет) либо эмир, либо ишак сдохн(у/е)т

Tags: грамматика

Какое грамматическое число должно быть у глагола в такой конструкции?

*Оффтоп. Я живой, если это кому-то еще интересно*

Comment: Я бы сказал в единственном.

Comment: Оффтоп. Это прекрасно.

Comment: Оффтоп.. А здесь практически вообще никого нет.

Comment: @Sharon время такое. А для меня это еще и очень личное...

Comment: Тире в первой части (*либо — эмир*) могло бы внести ясность в согласование.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***За двадцать лет либо эмир, либо ишак сдохнет.***

Выбор согласования в числе регламентируется правилом Розенталя. §190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

В пользу мн. числа говорит только препозиция подлежащих. Выбор ед. числа делаем по следующим признакам.

1. Раздельность действия каждого  лица.
2. Сказуемое выражено глаголом бытия или состояния.
3. Разделительные союзы, причем нет необходимости согласование по числу.
4. Контактное расположение второго подлежащего и сказуемого (ишак сдохнет). То есть нет явного рассогласования по числу, что негативно воспринимается на слух.

Comment: Да вот мне тоже  единственное ближе... На уровне интуиции. Но по смыслу как-то не то получается. И Розенталь тут как-то не убедителен. Возможно, я просто не в той форме...

Comment: Интуитивно мы понимаем так: хотя бы кто-нибудь из них сдохнет. Хотя не исключено, что оба, но это уже не так важно.

Comment: Согласен. Убедили.